# Download google offline map from PC?

Tags: google-maps

I have an android device that has no internet connection.

Is there a way to download a google map for a certain region from my PC, and then copy this map to my android device so that I can use it offline there?

Specifically, I want the full map of Cuba, with all zoom levels.

Comment: related: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/81692/6813

Answer (score 2):

You can not use Google Maps in offline mode according to its description. There are some tutorials in the Internet like these [Google Maps Offline](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-google-maps-offline-on-ios-android/) but are not recommended as it lasts only for 30 days in your device according to the tutorial. So looking at alternatives we have this app called [Maps.Me](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mapswithme.maps&hl=en) which is totally as good as Google Maps. I have this app for myself. Try it.

Comment: I can second MANI (though I use a different app as replacement). *Google Maps* so-called "offline-mode" is rather a very limited fake. Luckily there are plenty of alternatives. For more, you're welcome to check my list on [Navigation apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/travel_positioning_navigation).