# Download MAPS.ME (MapsWithMe) offline map from PC?

Tags: maps

I have an Android device that has no internet connection. I managed to install MAPS.ME (MapsWithMe) on this device.

Where can I download good (detailed) offline maps to use with this app? I am interested in a complete map of Cuba. Importantly, I must download the map from a PC, and then copy this file to the device, since the device has no internet connection. How can I do this?

Comment: related: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/32613/6813

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the direct link to download the map data: http://direct.mapswithme.com/direct/latest/

Comment: Looks like the link is forbidden now. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 6):

The maps data is stored in `/sdcard/MapsWithMe/`. For each downloaded map, there are 2/3 files (depending with route or not) and 1 folder:

- `<Country>` folder (empty)
- `Country.mwm` for map data
- `Country.mwm.routing` for its routing (direction) data

You need to download the map data from your PC (using Android emulator*, refer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3521/is-it-possible-to-install-android-on-a-pc/3523).), transfer the data from the emulator to your PC, then transfer the data again from your PC to your physical device.

<sup>* for Android emulator, I recommend [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/) since it's simple enough for general end-users. You can refer to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/105503/how-to-transfer-files-between-bluestacks-and-windows-pc/) to transfer between BlueStacks and PC.</sup>

<sup>**Disclaimer**: I don't have any affiliations to BlueStacks. I just tried it and found that it's easier to use than Android SDK emulator and using ADB to pull the files</sup>