# Download offline map packages of OsmAnd Map on PC?

Tags: applications, offline, maps, navigation, offline-map

I need to download offline map packages that users download from OsmAnd Map application.

Where can I find those packages on phone? or how can I download it online on PC? Similar to how it was answered for Maps.me application here: [Download MAPS.ME (MapsWithMe) offline map from PC?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/81692/download-maps-me-offline-map-from-pc).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Country maps can be downloaded [here](http://download.osmand.net/rawindexes/), and Overlay maps of antique/historical cities can be downloaded [here](http://www.geotiek.nl).

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely possible. It took me sometime to figure this out though. I found the page about how-to add maps manually to OsmAnd maps on Google Docs. There is some tutorial about this thing. Just head over to [OsmAnd Maps Download via PC](https://code.google.com/p/osmand/wiki/HowToDownloadData).